# Embed database to application in C#/VB.net

Tags: c#

Can we embed database to application in C#.net/vb.net?

Comment: @samsol: stop saying "c#.net". It makes you sound ignorant.

Comment: Yes we can embed datebase to appliaction in C#/BN.NET.

Comment: @TcKs: Yes is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Walter: It is correct answer to asked question, but is useless. I wanted point to the wrong question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use serverless RDBMS such as `SQL Server Compact` or `SQLite`.

Answer (score 2):

Sure if you put [**SQLite**](http://www.sqlite.org/) file as a resource (embedded) you could then run that file in memory stream (I think) of write it out as a file on runtime and delete it when closing down.

[.NET SQLite Wrapper/dll](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use **SqlLite** or **VistaDB** and store the db file as an assembly reource and extract the db file upon first run in the same directory where primary executable is residing.

Answer (score 2):

If your planning of using **Sqlite** and you should, I recommend you use this provider **http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ (it's open source)** with good support from an active community.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Firebird Embedded](http://www.firebirdsql.org/). It is free software.
There are .NET Data Provider for it.